# How I Prove $\sup(A)^{\sup(B)}=\sup(A^B)$

Tags: real-analysis

How I Prove

$\sup(A)^{\sup(B)}=\sup(A^B)$

Assume that $A,B\subset{\Bbb R}$ are both bounded, $x>0$ for $x\in A\cup B$ with $A^B=\{a^b\in \Bbb R\mid a\in A\ \land b\in B\ \}$

Part 1

$\sup(A)^{\sup(B)}\ge \sup(A^B)$

We know $\sup(A) \ge a \land \sup(B) \ge b\ $ so $\sup(A)^{\sup(B)}\ge a^b$, and $A^B$ is bounded then $\sup(A)^{\sup(B)}\ge \sup(A^B)$

Part 2

$\sup(A)^{\sup(B)}\le \sup(A^B)$

???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. For instance, take $A = \left\lbrace \frac 12 \right\rbrace$ and $B=\{1,2 \}$